# show implementation that would generically display one line per record filed

Tags: haskell

I have very long data types with a lot of records on them. The default show implementation when using deriving (Show) is not suitable anymore as it spreads on several lines (and become not human readeable) . That is why I want to instance show for my data types wih something that would output one line per record field

Consider the following snippet where show Dog is what I want to have:

```
data Cat = Cat { catname :: String , catcolor :: String } deriving (Eq, Show)
cat1 = Cat "Garfield" "orange"
cats = [ cat1 , Cat "Tom" "grey"] 

data Dog = Dog { dogname :: String , dogcolor :: String } deriving (Eq)
instance Show ( Dog ) where 
 show (Dog named colord)= "Dog {\n dogname = "++named++"  \n dogcolor = " ++ colord ++ "\n }\n"

dog1 = Dog "comet" "white"
dog2 = Dog "Odie" "yellow"

dogs = [dog1, dog2 ]

main = do { print cat1;
            print cats;
            print dog1;
            print dogs
}
```

When run it gives the following :

```
*Main> main
Cat {catname = "Garfield", catcolor = "orange"}
[Cat {catname = "Garfield", catcolor = "orange"},Cat {catname = "Tom", catcolor = "grey"}]
Dog {
 dogname = comet
 dogcolor = white
 }

[Dog {
 dogname = comet
 dogcolor = white
 }
,Dog {
 dogname = Odie
 dogcolor = yellow
 }
]
*Main>
```

How to achieve this result in a generic way, i.e not specific to data type Dog ? 
(for example in Java it would be with introspection) 
I have many Data types with many record fields so doing one implementation per data is not an option

Comment: Why not `pretty-simple`? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-simple

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : OMG that's what I need !  Thanks !

Comment: or [pretty-show](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-show)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know the package `pretty-simple` mentionned in a comment.

To get a pretty print, I use the package `pretty-show` (I cannot live without this package BTW).

```
import Text.Show.Pretty

data Cat = Cat { catname :: String , catcolor :: String } 
            deriving (Eq, Show)
data Dog = Dog { dogname :: String , dogcolor :: String } 
            deriving (Eq, Show)

cat1 = Cat "Garfield" "orange"
cats = [cat1 , Cat "Tom" "grey"] 

dog1 = Dog "comet" "white"
dog2 = Dog "Odie" "yellow"
dogs = [dog1, dog2 ]

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    pPrint cat1
    pPrint cats
    pPrint dog1
    pPrint dogs
```

This gives:

```
Cat { catname = "Garfield" , catcolor = "orange" }
[ Cat { catname = "Garfield" , catcolor = "orange" }
, Cat { catname = "Tom" , catcolor = "grey" }
]
Dog { dogname = "comet" , dogcolor = "white" }
[ Dog { dogname = "comet" , dogcolor = "white" }
, Dog { dogname = "Odie" , dogcolor = "yellow" }
]
```

Another useful function in `pretty-show` is `ppShow :: Show a => a -> String`, which converts a generic value into a pretty String (if possible). Then the `pPrint` function is nothing but

```
pPrint = putStrLn . ppShow
```